# Defining different delay time for individual units within the same resource pool

Tags: anylogic

I have set up an Agent called "operator" with parameters "name", "productivity1" and "productivity2". These parameters are fetched from a database. The numbers represent the seconds needed to complete a task.

```
name | productivity1 | productivity2
------------------------------------
Ann  | 65.9          | 45.1  
Bob  | 67.1          | 61.2
```

I have also set a resource pool called "operators" which takes in "operator" as unit.

In my model I have 2 service blocks, i.e. "Task1" and "Task2", is it possible to link the delay time of these blocks to the parameters of individual operators?

Answer (score 0):

possible, but not straight forward. In my experience, creating specific resourcepool-agents is a bit of a pain. They are supposed to be similar and making them have different characteristics is possible but again: not straight-forward.

Maybe you can redesign your model so your operators act as pure agents, i.e. the services do not pull from a resource pool but only work when on of your operator agents is free (use a state chart for that) and then you can easily use the operators characteristics for the delay.